# CakePHP: making a controller function not accessible

Tags: cakephp

I have an admin controller that I would like to utilize functions in other controllers (these functions do not represent pages that someone would load in their browser), but it cannot utilize those functions because the functions in the other controllers are private. They are private because I don't want the public to access them. Is there a way to make a controller function not accesible to the public without making the function private or protected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function __blah(){
// function that can't be accessed from outside, but can be called from other functions
}
```

Comment: Methods prefixed with one or more underscores are ignored by the router and therefore used to be the ideal way to create utility functions in your controller; in PHP4. If they're not meant to be accessed though, why not make them protected? 

In addition (because the TS is speaking of some "admin controller"), the method would need to be in the AppController for other controllers to access it though, otherwise you obviously have no way to reach them without importing the other controller (and if you're doing that, you're doing something wrong ;]).

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've read in the comment of the answer Piotr gave you:

You don't use an admin controller. You want to use admin prefixes:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing

And authentication:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

If you call - and thats how your comment sounds like - one controller from another you're doing something totally wrong in an MVC framework. If it should be re-usable code it should go into components if it's about admin action use the prefix routing and admin_* methods, auth component and protected methods for what you call "helper" methods.

Comment: I never know how to word these questions. But what I have is a controller that handles user related functions, like changing a user's password. It belongs in the user controller. I now want to add an admin controller, but I want it to leverage the private functions in the user controller. The end of your answer seems interesting, but I am not sure I really get what you are saying. Thanks for the response.

Comment: burzum is correct, prefix routing is what you're looking for. Whereas the URL `/users/add` maps to the function `add` in UsersController, `/admin/users/add` will map to `admin_add` in UsersController. You can then require auth in whatever way you please by checking for the 'admin' prefix URL param in AppController.

Comment: To be honest I do not know how to explain it better than the two links I provided. But first, do you know what MVC means and how it works?

Comment: It's been a while since this answer has been posted. Just updating burzum's link:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You have a lot of information in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/) about [ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists) (access control list) and that is exactly what you're looking for.

Or you may use [Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication) component.

Comment: I am not trying to make pages (controllers/functions) that are auth only. I have functions in controllers that are more of helper functions related to that controller that doesn't represent a page. I don't want those function to be accesible to the public, but I would like to be able to call those function from my admin controller to perform that function.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible solutions (they can also be combined):

The first solution is to move the code you want to reuse to [components](http://book.cakephp.org/view/996/Creating-Components) (as mentioned by burzum).

The second solution depends on your code. It's possible that you do stuff in the controller which should be done in the model. In this case, move the respective code to the model.

The third solution is to put the code you want to reuse into plain old PHP classes and [load them as vendor files](http://book.cakephp.org/view/943/Loading-Vendor-Files).